# Need help creating modular, plug-and-play type directives for an AngularJS mortgage app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, using-directives

I'm pretty new to Angular (and JS for that matter), and am trying to wrap my head around scope, controllers, and directives. I am currently working on a Comparative Mortgage app that will allow a user to compare the cost of two loans. Ideally, each set of mortgage data will be passed to one (or a number of) directive(s) that will perform the necessary calculations and bind to that dataset's respective "modules" (form, table, amortization schedule, graphs, etc). I would like all of a dataset's "modules" to update dynamically, so a change in Loan A's form will be reflected in all of Loan A's modules automatically. I will also need to pass some data from each Loan to a parent controller/scope, which will allow me perform comparisons from Loan A and B.

I've managed to get some of this working by nesting directives.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<mort-data mortgage="1" id="mort_a" ng-init="mortInstance = 1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div ng-include="'templates/forms/userMortForm.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div ng-include="'templates/tables/userMortTable.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <mort-schedule>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="mort1_sch" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-auto-resize class="grid"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="toggleWaste.value" ng-click="includeWaste()"> Include Insurance
                & Tax</label>
        </mort-schedule>
    </div>
</mort-data>
```

```
.directive('mortData', function (dataServices) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: {
            pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                 scope.data = {};
                 scope.data.salePrice = 9999999;

             //define mortgage vars here and perform calculations 
        }
    }
})
.directive('mortSchedule', function (uiGridConstants, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.data.amortSchedule = {};

           //build amortization schedule here
        }
   }
})
```

Using this method twice give me two distinct, isolated mortgage datasets. As I understand it, I am creating an inherited scope for each mortData instance, and passing that scope to its respective, nested mortSchedule directive.
But, I'm pretty sure that this structure will not allow me to eventually pass data from each mortData directive to a parent controller and perform the desired comparisons. It seems like it will also depend on continually nested directives, which strikes me as messy and limiting.

I'm wondering what the "Angular" way to approach this project is. Am I going about it all wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you tell me the reason behind creating two directives?

Comment: I don't really have a good reason. It just seemed reasonable that each directive would build one "module." Even if all logic for all "modules" was contained in one directive, wouldn't I still have the same problem of not being able to pass data up to the parent controller?

Comment: are you creating directives for the first time?

Comment: Yes, this is my first time working with directives.

Comment: if you can explain me this in short may be would be greatly help ful

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know how to summarize this much more.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provides ways to change the scope inheritance pattern in a couple of ways

1. You can use an isolated scope (include a `scope: { something: something}` in your directive definition). Isolated scopes will be taken out of the general inheritance tree, and will have their own independent existence. You can choose what should reside within your isolated scope, and what relation these objects should have to the outside world like so.

   `scope: {
      a: @outerA // Text binding,
      b: &outerB // One-way data binding
      c: =outerC // Two way data binding
   }`
2. You can have a transcluded scope (include a `transclude: true` in your directive definition). Transcluded scopes have access to the scope **outside** the directive. This type of directives are useful when you want the directive to wrap around arbitrary values and be plug and play. This works in your use case I think.

   ```
   angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
   .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'Tobias';
   }])
   .directive('myDialog', function() {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       transclude: true,
       scope: {},
       template: '<div ng-controller="Controller">
                       <my-dialog>Check out the contents, {{name}}!</my-dialog>
                 </div>',
       link: function(scope) {
         scope.name = 'Jeff';
       }
     };
   });
   ```

This example for instance, has access to the outer controller ($scope.name = 'Tobias') as opposed to the `link` function (`$scope.name = 'Jeff'`)